Función de potencia pow en Pascal
He querido recrear la funcion pow() en lenguaje pascal
Necesito ayuda, alguien me puede ayudar?
Aquí el código:
program pow;
var
A: Integer
B: Integer

function potencia(x: Integer; y: Integer; ): Integer
begin
var
c: Integer
for c := 1 to y do
  x := x * x
  end;
  potencia := x
  end;
  begin 
  Read(A)
write(potencia(a, 3)); 
end:

La cree similar a cómo lo hubiera hecho en python

No sé pascal pero parece que tus errores son de sintaxis. El más llamativo es que las sentencias llevan ; además que el end final debería ir con . en lugar de : Estudia mejor la sintaxis

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Esto compila?

Hay varios problemas con tu código, vamos uno a uno:

al declarar una función o procedimiento, el último parámetro de la lista no lleva punto y coma y la declaración al final, si lo lleva. Así, la declaración de la función podría ser:
function potencia(x: Integer; y: Integer): Integer;

Además, cuando tienes varios parámetros consecutivos del mismo tipo, puedes hacer una lista separada por comas y colocar el tipo al final de la lista, así:
function potencia(x, y: Integer): Integer;


En el pascal clásico y en muchos sabores modernos, debes declarar todas las variables locales antes del begin de la función, procedimiento o método. Dado que no indicas qué compilador usas, sugiero que muevas la declaración de variables a ese lugar.

La declaración de cada variable también debe terminar con punto y coma.

Debes considerar el caso de elevar un número a la potencia 0. En ese caso, el resultado de la función es 1, excepto si el número a elevar es 0, en ese caso, debes generar un error. Si tu sabor de pascal soporta excepciones, esa sería la mejor ruta a seguir.

En versiones modernas de pascal, como la de Delphi o de Free Pascal, puedes usar la variable automática result para almacenar el resultado de la función. Al terminar, automágicamente se devolverá el valor almacenado en esa variable. En pascal clásico, yo usualmente declaro esta variable, para el mismo fin, solo que hay que devolver manualmente el valor al final.

El programa termina con un end seguido de punto: end.

Todas las sentencias terminan con un punto y coma.


Finalmente, algunas recomendaciones, que no son obligatorias, pero si mejoran la legibilidad del código:

Usa nombres de variables significativos. En ciclos, es válido usar variables con un nombre no significativo, y lo habitual es usar I, J, K, etc. Leer un ciclo con una variable C, aunque no tiene nada de malo, a mi me hace ruido...
Identa bien el código. Si vienes de python, eso debiera resultarte bastante natural.
Declara las variables globales antes del begin principal. Esto evitará que las uses inadvertidamente en las funciones o procedimientos que estén declarados antes.

Así, te dejo dos posibles programas, uno para pascal clásico (como el de Turbo Pascal) y otro para pascal moderno, como el de Delphi o de Free Pascal.
Pascal clásico:
program pow;

function Potencia(Base, Exponente: Integer): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
  Result: Integer;
begin
  if (Base = 0) and (Exponente = 0) then
    Result := -1  { ojo, esto es incorrecto, pero no hay muchas }
                  { maneras de indicar un error }
  else
  begin
    Result := 1;
    for I := 1 to Exponente do
      Result := Result * Base;
  end;
  Potencia := Result;
end;

var
  A: Integer;
begin 
  Readln(A);
  Writeln(Potencia(A, 3)); 
end.

Pascal moderno:
program pow;

function Potencia(Base, Exponente: Integer): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if (Base = 0) and (Exponente = 0) then
    raise Exception.Create('Error de división por cero');  //o el mensaje que creas conveniente
  Result := 1;
  for I := 1 to Exponente do
    Result := Result * Base;
end;

var
  A: Integer;
begin 
  Readln(A);
  Writeln(Potencia(A, 3)); 
end.

